# When I am developing an Android application ,I want to adjust to the volume of Music with a seekbar,how do it?

Tags: android, volume, seekbar

When I develop an Android application, I want to adjust to the volume of Music with a seekbar. How can this be done? 
In addition, when I adjust the volume of Music, I don't want to display a Toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this code......

```
    SeekBar ring = null;
AudioManager mgr = null;
    mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     ring = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    initBar(ring, AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

please call the function initbar using your seekbar view instance and stream it will set the music volume as you increase or decrease the seekbar...

```
private void initBar(SeekBar bar, final int stream) {
    bar.setMax(mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(stream));
    bar.setProgress(mgr.getStreamVolume(stream));

    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            mgr.setStreamVolume(stream, progress,
                    AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
            // no-op
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
            // no-op
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more explanation? Code only is not welcome here...